# Copy SSH-keys between hosts

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I'm performing:

```
# copy public key to other hosts
for host in ec2-master.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com \
ec2xxx.compute.amazonaws.com \
ec2xxx.compute.amazonaws.com; \
do ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $host; \
done
```

So I try to copy the key I've generated on ec2-master.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com to the other servers.
But I still get

```
/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
The authenticity of host 'ec2xxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (10.0.xx.xx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 3a:63xx:a6:19:xx:23:d1:xx:06:22:xx:a0:b9:8c:xx:cf.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

So I got a permission denied. But I don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: input `yes` and what happen?

Comment: I've inputed yes. But the permission is still denied. When I try it again it will not ask the ECDSA key fingerprint again but will still return a permission denied

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try changing the `ssh-copy-id` command to:</strike>

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ec2-user@$host
```

(assuming you're using Amazon Linux -- use `ubuntu` as the user if you are using Ubuntu)

**Update:**

I think the problem may be because you are trying to copy a *new key* over to a host that only accepts logins using an *existing key* (no passwords allowed).

I couldn't get this to work with `ssh-copy-id`, but you can do it with a standard ssh command:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -i AWS_key.pem centos@$host "cat - >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Where `AWS_key.pem` is the private part of the key pair that AWS attached to your instance when you launched it.

Comment: I tried it with my user centos and with root. But still the same issue. My reference to try this loop is from: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/prerequisites.html (at the end of the page)

Comment: user centos because my amazon ec2 has centos as OS

Comment: I did not use a .pem-key for ssh'n because of this issue.

Comment: What do you use instead? @user5558501

Answer (score 1):

SSH is trying to tell you that authentication into your hosts has **failed** and what **authentication methods** were tried.

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

This is what the `(publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)` portion of the log output is telling you.

It is telling you it attempted to authenticate against **publickey**, **gssapi-keyex**, and **gssapi-with-mic** authentication methods.

*Typically* you or AWS provide an **ssh** keypair to be used prelaunch setup.

The **sshd** config is also set to authenticate using the keypairs (public + private key = Public Key Encryption hence **publickey** mentioned in the ssh log).

Therefore, your command

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $host;
```

is wrong for a few reasons.

1. You don't specify a specific user to login against unless the username of your local host matches your remote machine (for AWS the user could be `ec2-user`, `centos`, `ubuntu`, **etc**
2. Even if the usernames were to match correctly, since **AWS** *effectively* (I am not familiar with GSSAPI) only enables ssh keypair authentication, you would only be able to login with the private key chosen or generated at EC2 instance creation.

If there were some **alternative authentication mechanism** configured on the host **i.e.** `user:password` then you would be able to run a modified version of the command.

```
REMOTE_USER=ec2-user
...
do ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub $REMOTE_USER@$host
```

However, you would be prompted for a user/password each time.

**Note** The above command assumes you have enabled a user/pass authentication mechanism (Could be temporarily). However, for just 3 hosts I might just manually install the keypair at this point.

The language from the "**Copy the key to a server**" from [sshd.com](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/copy-id) seems to imply that password-based authentication is enabled initially on the hosts.

"Once an SSH key has been created, the ssh-copy-id command can be used to install it as an authorized key on the server. Once the key has been authorized for SSH, it grants access to the server without a password."

Answer (score 0):

I use this script and it works for me:
Сan you try this

```
for host in ${hosts[*]}
do
echo $host
ssh-keyscan $host | tee -a ~/.ssh/known_hosts
sshpass -p 'mypass' ssh-copy-id myuser@$host
done
```

Comment: This is valid on AWS? The question it's related to aws and i believe that AWS has some problems with ssh and passwords according to the other answer.